"import.meta" is not available in the configured target environment
Getting this error:
"import.meta" is not available in the configured target environment ("es2017") and will be empty [empty-import-meta]
I have developed extension in directus project. Because I am importing the file from api/src/services because of that now I am getting this error.
My file structure:
project-root/
├── api/
│   ├── extensions/
│   │   └── getallproducts/
│   │       ├── src/
│   │       │   ├── index.ts
│   │       │   └── ...
│   │       ├── tsconfig.json
│   │       └── ...
├── src
└── ...


My tsconfig.json code:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2019",
        "lib": ["ES2019", "DOM"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictBindCallApply": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "rootDir": "../../src",
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}


Want to get rid of import-meta error.
